# Send log using fluentd from one GCP project to another GCP project

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, fluentd, google-cloud-logging

I need to do a setup where I nee to send logs from one GCP Project to another GCP Project.
We will have two central projects: `application-logging` and `application monitoring`. The application projects will be monitored using central monitoring project `application monitoring` via shared GCP Monitoring Workspace.
But I am not able to find any config similar to monitoring for logging. For example:
My GCE instance will reside in `application-project` and from that instance I need to send logs using fluentd to `application-logging` project in Stackdriver.

Let me know if any solution exists for this scenario.
Don't want to use Log Sink.

Comment: adding some code would always help more clarity.

Comment: There is no code, I am just trying to find a solution from architecture perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a product manager with Cloud Logging. This is a relatively new feature that comes with log buckets. You can redirect logs from App GCP Project to Central Logging GCP project.
A few resources that might be helpful:

- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/central-log-storage - guide is for setting this up at the org level but can be adapted for the project level
- https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/cloud-logging-adds-log-buckets-feature - blog post walking through the feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that without "fluentd". You need to create a sink to export logs with Custom destination send your logs from one project to a destination in another project. The documentation on how to do it can be found in oficial GCP [page](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export).

Comment: Yes, that is also a solution but In this case flow will be like:
`Logs from App Instance` -> `StackDriver in App GCP Project` <br>

`StackDriver in App GCP Project` -> `StackDriver in Central Logging GCP Project`

What I am looking for is:

`Logs from App Instance` -> `StackDriver in Central Logging GCP Project`